# GraphQL and Meteor.js data tracking

Tags: reactjs, meteor, graphql

I was wondering if there's some way to use the benefits of Meteor.js tracker with GraphQL as a data layer for a React view. 
Something like auto-updating the view, by updating the props when the content changes in the Database.
I know there are mutations, will it help in fetching again the data once it has been called?

Comment: add  code snippet  to be able to figure out your issue

Comment: Actually, I just figured out the solution. You need to define mutation and refetch as a callback. But this only works for one client. One mutation is not repercuted on other clients UI. In my case, when I'll need a dynamic refresh/ tracking on data change I'll apply publish/subscribe and when hot reload will not be necessary, an Apollo client will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on the context of the application,
you effectively needs to refetch a query after a mutation to affect the change on your UI.

You need to ask you the good questions :

- Do you need real time data synchronization on several users screen
- Do you need a performant web application when real time data tracking is not a worry.

If performance is a constraint I'd suggest you to go for a 100% GraphQL solution,
if you need user collaboration the easiest way to go is Meteor Tracked data, but it costs a lot in memory.